# Where is source of Kmail problem - imap "Server is not available"?

Tags: email, imap, kmail

Normally, on my laptop, Kmail can access my email from the 1and1 IMAP server (imap.1and1.com) easily. Today, Kmail 5.4.3 (Kubuntu 17.04) shows "server is not available" The gmail imap server is available.
My android smart phone can access pop.1and1.com.

Kmail can send mail via smtp.1and1.com
Kmail can receive mail via pop.1and1.com

ufw (uncomplicated firewall) is inactive

What strategy can I use for looking for the source of this problem?

Comment: well you seem to have answered your own question "My android smart phone can access pop.1and1.com".   It is a pop server not an imap server.

Comment: Well no, 1and1 supports both IMAP and POP. I have been using IMAP with Kmail on my laptop; it stopped working today. I want to know how I can figure out why I can no longer access IMAP from Kmail on my laptop

Comment: This morning I booted Kubuntu and Kmail could download from the 1and1 server.  Now at 9:45, it can no longer. Maybe the server is down (although I can access through webmail and through pop).  How can I check?  Ping doesn't seem to work on these type of urls.  I'm not sure www.isitdownrightnow.com will either. I don't have another imap client to check from - that would tell me if the problem is with Kmail.

Comment: the easiest way to tell is to configure kmail to use the pop server.

Comment: OK, @ravery, I've verified Kmail is working with POP. Now I'm trying to check on the imap server.  
telnet pop.1and1.com 110      gets a response
telnet imap.1and1.com 993     gets "connection timed out"
telnet smtp.1and1.com 587     gets a response
     Does this mean the 1and1 imap server is actually down?  Is there a way to verify this with an SSH command or something else?

Comment: I can ping pop.1and1.com and smtp.1and1.com but not imap.1and1.com I'm thinking this means the 1and1 imap server is down.

Comment: you just verified, imap.1and1.com is down. use the pop server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1and1's imap server *is* down.  I verified this by telnet and pinging on the smtp, pop and imap servers:

`telnet pop.1and1.com 110` returned a response

`telnet imap.1and1.com 993` returned "connection timed out"

`telnet smtp.1and1.com 587` returned a response

`ping pop.1and1.com` works

`ping imap.1and1.com`   times out

`ping smtp.1and1.com`   works

This was a confusing problem initially because I could also not access webmail although someone else could. I corrected the url to access webmail. I set up a Kmail account with pop and so verified Kmail with pop was working.  So that left me with just Kmail not being able to access the imap server.